# Сan you explain why I get an error globalizing a variable?

Tags: python, function

**Hey!**

This relates to problem 18 from Euler's project (https://projecteuler.net/problem=18)

This code solved it, but I got an error (4th line):

```
Undefined variable: 'ans'Python(undefined-variable)
```

So, I want to understand why this happened

Also, let me know, if there are any flaws in my code

Thanks in advance

```
def brute(i, j, sum):
    global ans
    if i > len(l) - 1:
        if sum > ans:
            ans = sum
        return None
    brute(i + 1, j, sum + l[i][j])
    brute(i + 1, j + 1, sum + l[i][j])


l = [
    [75],
    [95, 64],
    [17, 47, 82],
    [18, 35, 87, 10],
    [20, 4, 82, 47, 65],
    [19, 1, 23, 75, 3, 34],
    [88, 2, 77, 73, 7, 63, 67],
    [99, 65, 4, 28, 6, 16, 70, 92],
    [41, 41, 26, 56, 83, 40, 80, 70, 33],
    [41, 48, 72, 33, 47, 32, 37, 16, 94, 29],
    [53, 71, 44, 65, 25, 43, 91, 52, 97, 51, 14],
    [70, 11, 33, 28, 77, 73, 17, 78, 39, 68, 17, 57],
    [91, 71, 52, 38, 17, 14, 91, 43, 58, 50, 27, 29, 48],
    [63, 66, 4, 68, 89, 53, 67, 30, 73, 16, 69, 87, 40, 31],
    [4, 62, 98, 27, 23, 9, 70, 98, 73, 93, 38, 53, 60, 4, 23],
]
ans = 0
brute(0, 0, 0)
print(ans)
```

Comment: I ran your code and it worked fine, but you should avoid using `globals` it's a bad practice.

Comment: Python does allow globals to be defined in methods. I was unable to reproduce your error: https://repl.it/repls/ThoroughFrostyCables

Comment: It's probably the code parser of the website getting it wrong. Otherwise how can your code solve the problem and also have an error in it?

Comment: What environment are you using which reports the error? That's not coming from the Python interpreter.

Comment: I am using VS Code with Python extension.

Comment: Also how can I avoid using global here?

Comment: The same ways you always avoid using globals, passing values to functions and returning values from functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO this is not a good use-case for globals, would be better to refactor the code like so:

```
def brute(i, j):
    if i > len(l) - 1:
        return 0
    return l[i][j]+max(brute(i + 1, j), brute(i + 1, j + 1))
```

I've flipped the logic around to accomplish though, the code works by picking the maximum sum from its subtree

You ideally want to save usage of global variables for system-wide settings and such

Comment: But how can I print the answer using this method?

Comment: it doesnt work... or i am doing something wrong https://repl.it/repls/ConcreteDutifulApplicationstack

Comment: should be fine now, but had to change the way the code works, you'll need to print out the return value of the function